# Error with numerical integration for three parameters optimization

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm trying to optimize three parameters simultaneously using the following code:

```
(* Input  *)
NN = 4;
energy = 16;
α = 0;
β = 100;
z = 1;


(* Lambda values *)
λ1 = z;
λ2 = (2 energy + λ1^2)/6;
λ3 = (2 λ1*λ2 - α)/6;
λ4 = (4 λ2^2 + 6 λ1 *λ3 - 2 β)/
   20;


(* Find the optimized parameters *)
Clear[ψ, μ, f, Δ];
ψ[λ2_][λ3_][λ4_][r_] := 
  Exp[-r - λ2 r^2 - λ3  r^3 - λ4  r^4];

μ[λ2_][λ3_][λ4_][k_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   r^k ψ[λ2][λ3][λ4][r], {r, 
    0, ∞}];

f[λ2_][λ3_][λ4_][k_] := 
  k (k - 1) μ[λ2][λ3][λ4][k - 1] + 
   2 z μ[λ2][λ3][λ4][k] + 
   2 energy μ[λ2][λ3][λ4][k + 1] - 
   2 α μ[λ2][λ3][λ4][k + 2] - 
   2 β μ[λ2][λ3][λ4][k + 3];

Δ[λ2_][λ3_][λ4_] := 
  Sum[f[λ2][λ3][λ4][k]^2, {k, 1, NN}];

new = FindMinimum[Δ[λ2][λ3][λ4],\
 {λ2, λ3, λ4}] // Quiet;


λ2 = new[[2, 1]][[2]];
λ3 = new[[2, 2]][[2]];
λ4 = new[[2, 3]][[2]];

energy = λ2*3 - 1/2;
Print["New energy  ", energy];
```

but it returns errors like this

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(-r-(11 r^3)/6+(17 r^4)/5-r^2
>   λ2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling
>   points in the region with boundaries {{∞,0.}}.

1- It is obvious that the integration procedure causes the errors, but I don't know how should I fix them?

2- Is my code to optimize three parameters true? (provided that I add a loop to my code) or does exist a more efficient way to do so?

Comment: Also related: [(a135026)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135026), [(a160052)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160052), [(q201657)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201657)

Comment: Thanks all, but if you note, the integration was not just my problem, I was looking for a method for optimizing three parameters too.

Comment: So the first two related links in my comment are in fact duplicates, too?

Comment: I don't know, maybe

Comment: The parameters `λ2, λ3, λ4` over which you're optimizing lack the `NumericQ` protection that lead to the `NIntegrate` errors. This is the same problem that the linked duplicate [(q22210)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22210) has, except for optimizing over two vector parameters instead of three. (Is two instead of three significant? Are vectors?) The related two Q&A have similar problems to yours, but those Qs were challenged by the notion of a ***minimal*** working example, and I didn't think they were good examples, compared with (q22210). They could be added to the list of dupes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completelly understood your computations, but this is my try. First, let me simplify a bit.

```
NN = 4;
energy = 16;
α = 0;
β = 100;
z = 1;

λ1 = z
λ2 = (2 energy + λ1^2)/6
λ3 = (2 λ1*λ2 - α)/6
λ4 = -(4 λ2^2 + 6 λ1*λ3 - 2 β)/20 (* changed sign here, otherwise the integral does not converge *)

Clear[ψ, μ, f, Δ];
ψ[λ2_?NumericQ, λ3_?NumericQ, λ4_?NumericQ, r_] := 
  Exp[-r - λ2 r^2 - λ3 r^3 - λ4 r^4];

μ[λ2_?NumericQ, λ3_?NumericQ, λ4_?NumericQ, k_] := 
  NIntegrate[r^k ψ[λ2, λ3, λ4, r], {r, 0, ∞}];

f[λ2_?NumericQ, λ3_?NumericQ, λ4_?NumericQ, k_] :=
 k (k - 1) μ[λ2, λ3, λ4, k - 1] + 2 z μ[λ2, λ3, λ4, k] + 
   2 energy μ[λ2, λ3, λ4, k + 1] - 
   2 α μ[λ2, λ3, λ4, k + 2] - 
   2 β μ[λ2, λ3, λ4, k + 3];

Δ[λ2_?NumericQ, λ3_?NumericQ, λ4_?NumericQ] := 
  Sum[f[λ2, λ3, λ4, k]^2, {k, 1, NN}];

min = NMinimize[{Δ[x2, x3, x4], x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0}, {x2, x3, x4}]
```

> `{0.0000396903, {x2 -> 6.71696, x3 -> 0.000223156, x4 -> 0.000143381}}`

And new energy:

```
newEnergy = (3 x2 - 1/2) /. min[[2]]
```

> `19.6509`

Comment: Thanks a lot. However the running time is so long (I waited for 10 min but it didn't finish), right?

Comment: Yes, it takes several minutes on my machine too.

Comment: OK. you're right, it finished finally in my laptop. 1- Please explain about the modifications you made to my code. specially what does `?NumericQ`command do and how it fixes the integration error? 2- I have to add a loop to my code, namely I have to use new values of λ2, λ3, λ4 in the next loop, How can I address this?

Comment: `?NumericQ` means that a function will work only with numerical argument, it is often used with numerical functions: `NIntegrate`, `NMinimize` require numerical imput. `NINtegrate` will not work if not provided with numerical coefficients except a variable of integration, see examples in help. Initial values of `λ2, λ3, λ4` are not used in further computations, those `λ` in functions' definitions are dummy variables, and you see I used `x` in minimization to not confuse with initial `λ`. `NMinimize` finds global minimum for `λ2, λ3, λ4`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I have to use the new value of energy to get new lambdas and repeat the calculations and obtain new energy again and so on